# P4 shelve of committed files

Tags: perforce

Is there any option to shelve files that have been once committed? I need to expose them for a codereview. I've tried to fetch old versions and shelve them to produce something like back-diff, however it doesn't work for me: although files in shelve are old one, diff in P4V thinks they're identical to new ones.

Comment: Why can the user not compare the changelist to previous revision?

Comment: Actually, this isn't immediately obvious, I'll post an answer below.

Comment: What do you mean by "...expose them for a code review."?  They are already exposed.  The reviewer need only look at the changelist you submitted.

Answer (score 3):

You can diff a submitted changelist against the depot at a previous state.  In your history tab, (View -> History in Menu Bar), select the changelist of interest.  Drag the changelist onto the previous changelist number (be sure you have the top level of your depot/workspace selected, or at least a high enough point to include all your changes).  This will open up a dialog which will be a type of directory diff which will show all the changed files.  Use the arrows in the toolbar to move between changed files.  Use the drag and drop and drag the old file onto the new one to see the changes between the files.

With the command line you can also do this:  let's pretend your changelist is 1300

```
p4 diff2 ...@1299    ...@1300
```

but this uses the text-only 'diff'.

Answer (score 1):

To produce the "back-diff" you wanted, you need to do the following:

1. Sync the relevant files to the revision you're interested in (p4 help sync)
2. Check out the relevant files into a new changelist (p4 help edit)
3. Sync the relevant files to the head revision (p4 help sync)
4. Resolve the files you have checked out by accepting target (p4 help resolve)
5. Shelve the files (p4 help shelve)

you can now provide the shelf as a diff of the changes that were made against head.

Answer (score 0):

No. The files have been committed.

You want to back out the changelist, shelve that changelist, then back out the changelist again and submit to restore the depot to the state before you submitted.

**How to do this**

1. In P4V, select the 'Submitted Changelists' tab (View > Submitted Changelists) and find the changelist. Right-click the changelist and select 'Back Out Submitted Changelist ###'. It will prompt you create a new **pending** changelist.
2. In the 'Pending Changelist' tab (View > Pending Changelists), shelve the new changelist you just created.
3. Repeat step 1, creating a new **pending** changelist.
4. Submit.